CSS Navbar Media Queries-
I'm a designer now working as a web dev (taught myself thru YT lol)
Working on a nav-bar for one of my first clients and struggling to make it responsive on smaller devices, and scratching my head as to how to control the width of the container whilst making its contents smaller.
Code is below and I've attached imgages of what it should look like at the width of a phone, I already have it designed and coded for laptop width.
Would it be better off to restyle the buttons in the media query, or just use the media query to scale it down as a whole?
Laptop Size:

Phone Size:

Inspector-1200px,Navbar gets cut off (?):

Inspector- >1200px, navbar starts to lose buttons underneath the logo:



/* --Start of NavBar styling */
.Nav-Link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.NavBar {
  /*NavBar nav div*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #ffecc0;
  font-size: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  row-gap: 8px;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 100;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .NavBar {
    width: 100vw;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    row-gap: 4px;
    height: fit-content;
  }
}

/* Logo ofc */
.logo {
  padding-left: 3rem;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #ffecc0;
}

#logo> {
  height: 80px;
}

.NavBarNav {
  /*NavButtons container*/
  background-color: #ffecc0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
  margin: 0%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  margin-right: 20px;

  padding-inline-end: 0.5rem;
  top: 0%;
  position: sticky;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100vw;
  gap: 8px;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .NavBarNav {
    padding: right 2rem;

    gap: 0.5rem;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}

.NavBtn {
  background-color: var(--cream-500);

  text-align: center;
  height: 59px;
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: #21100b;
  border: #ffecc0;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150) {
  .NavBtn {
    font-size: 8px;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: fit-content;
    width: min-content;
  }
}

/* NavBar Button animations */

.NavBtn:hover {
  background-color: #b79860;
  color: #21100b;
}

.NavBtn:focus,
.NavBtn:focus-within {
  /*
  Focus=within stops C700 being applied to whole navbar. 
  ---TO DO
  =fix pressed state*/
  background-color: #93713d;
  /* Cream 700 */
  color: #21100b;

  border: #21100b;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.Nav-Link {
  padding: 10px;

  font-size: 20px;
  color: #21100b;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
  .Nav-Link {
    padding: 3px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}

/* --END of NavBar styling */
<nav class="NavBar">
  <div class="logo">
    <span>
          <a href="Index.html">
            <img
              src="Assets\Wordmark\Dark.svg"
              alt="Alastair Smith Ceramics Brand logo and wordmark. Colour is Dark Chocolate."
            /> </a
        ></span>
  </div>

  <ul class="NavBarNav">
    <li class="NavItem">
      <button class="NavBtn">
            <a class="Nav-Link" state="active" href="Index.html">Home</a>
          </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="NavBtn">
            <a class="Nav-Link" href="About.html">About</a>
          </button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <button class="NavBtn">
            <a class="Nav-Link" href="Process.html">Creative Process</a>
          </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="NavBtn">
            <a class="Nav-Link" href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
          </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="NavBtn">
            <a class="Nav-Link" href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
          </button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="NavBtn">
            <a class="Nav-Link" href="#shop">Shop</a>
          </button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>




For responsive style you canot just reduce the size of the text, because it would be unreadable. Look for examples for other sites, 99% of them have an action button to open it in responsive. And if you are a beginner, just so you know, there are frameworks that help giving you tools ready to use, like bootstrap.

Nesting an interactive element within another interactive element is invalid HTML; choose either an <a> element or a <button> element, you can't nest them.

I don't see you using a font-family from the design. The default font is much wider. And your buttons should have a type attribute.
Usually, people make a hamburger menu on mobile navigation, since all of the links don't fit on the page and it's a job of a designer to plan it ahead as well, so it is good that you started making layouts yourself.
You might add a button for opening a menu on screens at which your links get cut off - it is usually a best practice. But you can also use a "Pixel Perfect" tool. It is a plugin for browser. You added a lot of useless styles which are doing nothing - find and delete them in order to clean the mess and then use the solution above or at least a display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; (but this second solution is going to look weird).
There are tools to convert design into html/css as well, at least I heard of them.
You should have this code at the beginning of your styles:
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

I suggest you to go check free FreeCodeCamp Responsive Web Design course, because right now, in my opinion you should either use some tools which are going to make this layout for you, or you will struggle a lot and probably without a purpose.

Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure why it didn't come through but there is a font family 'futura' in the stylesheet. I've changed it to a hamburger menu for mobile devices however i'm now left with what seems to be a 'ghost margin' on the right side of the entire element. Have you encountered this issue before? @feelsgood
